# Is there a value that is unique to a machine and only available to processes running locally on that machine?

Tags: encryption, encryption-symmetric

I have a client application that needs to read and write some encrypted data. It is supposed to be an automatically scheduled process without user interaction. This leads to the well-known problem of where to store the symmetric key that was used to encrypt the data. I can't store it on a different machine and I can't ask the user to enter a password every time the process runs. Therefore, I'm stuck saving the key on the same machine where the data resides, which is inherently insecure. If some attacker manages to grab both the data and the key file (the source code to the application is freely available), then they can decrypt the data.

I thought a somewhat more secure method would be to generate a key based on some value that is only available to locally running processes. Say, for sake of example, that every pc has a unique number that is unobtainable by other machines. I'd be able to grab that number and use that as a key. If an attacker managed to grab the encrypted data and the source code, they still wouldn't be able to decrypt the data because their machine would have a different number.

They could still, obviously, build an application that grabs the unique number and run that on my machine to obtain the unique number, but then they are remotely executing software which is already a step beyond simply being able to grab some files.

Does such a value exist on either Windows or Linux?

Comment: Windows CryptProtectData with `CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE` will encrypt data in a way that only the same machine can decrypt. You can also use user scope so it's encrypted so only that user (on any machine) can decrypt it.

Comment: Modern machines should have access to a [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) which can store a (truly random) key securely.